# Autohotkey Get everything before a regex

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to get the movie name (without the dots) in a string.

For example:

"Matrix.1999.LIMITED.720p.BluRay"
would be 
"Matrix"

Also,
"Max.Steel.2016.1080p.BluRay"
would be
"Max Steel"

I have made the below but its not working

```
Haystack =Max.Steel.2016.1080p.BluRay
TheYear := RegExMatch(Haystack, "\d{4}\b")
StringGetPos, YearPostion,Haystack,%TheYear%
StringLeft, MovieName,Haystack,%YearPostion%
MsgBox, %MovieName%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all of the dots with whitespace, search for the year, and trim the unnecessary whitespace:

```
Haystack = Max.Steel.2016.1080p.BluRay
StringReplace, Haystack, Haystack , . , %A_Space% , All
TheYear := RegExMatch(Haystack, "(1|2)\d\d\d")
if( TheYear > 0 )
{
    TheYear--
    StringLeft, MovieName,Haystack,%TheYear%
    MovieName := Trim( MovieName ) ;
    MsgBox, |%MovieName%|
}
```